# UI scaling in kivy on MacOS with retina display

Tags: macos, kivy, scaling

I've written an app in kivy for MacOS and Windows, however on MacOS there are problems with inconsistent UI scaling when moving windows between monitors, the app looks fine on retina (2017 MacBook Pro), but when moved to a secondary display (1920x1080 24'' monitor) all the scaled elements, text, buttons etc. become huge.

Here what the app looks like on Windows and on retina display (correct):

### Correct

[image: correct]

Here's what it looks like when moved from retina to another display (wrong):

### Incorrect

[image: incorrect]

I tried using kivy.metrics.sp, dp and others according to documentation but no joy. A working example to reproduce the issue:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.metrics import sp
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '50')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mylayout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        mybutton = Button(text="TEST", font_size=sp(20))  
        mylayout.add_widget(mybutton)
        return mylayout

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I think this is arising from the transition between high and low dpi displays, while Kivy selects the dpi scaling just once at startup. I'm not sure if there's any nice solution.

Comment: how about an ugly solution? is there a way to force recalculation of the dpi scaling and redraw the ui?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that you can write some code to do that, but I can't suggest any straightforward way to do it. There might be one if you dive into the code.